# SignalR to create a realtime database notification for one user instance only

Tags: c#, signalr, sqldependency

I'm trying to use SignalR to create a real time notification like facebook I'm using c# as server side language 
1- i read the wiki in github and I know that I can notify only the connected user my main goal is to use the signalR  with sql to get data from database and notify the connected user 
2- i know I should use sql dependencies class but the example I see on the internet is about MVC and my project isn't MVC it's pure web site

Can anyone help me with an example for how to achieve this ?

reference about signalR :

```
https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs
```

appreciate your help

Comment: something like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14321791/463785

Comment: No not really that's an MVC based it's the example i saw obviously is their any non MVC example ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a database to persist data but with SignalR there's no need to poll data from the database in order to provide "push" notifications.

On the server side of things, whenever a client say "sends a message" just use the SignalR server to notify anyone who's currently connected that needs to be notified

In the case that you want to notify a user who is offline, persist that data to the database and then on the initial logon of the offline user pull that data and notify them accordingly.

A good sample for utilizing SignalR for push notifications (chat messages) and still persisting data is JabbR: **https://github.com/davidfowl/JabbR**

Comment: you provided an answer that i actually now my problem is not in the concept i have a problem in the implementation